# How to manipulate this JSON using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am getting this response from an API:

```
{
  "statuses": {
    "status": [
      {
        "name": "Member", 
        "id": "1"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "Attender", 
        "id": "3"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "Child", 
        "id": "4"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I need to somehow flatten the response to be this:

```
{
  "name": "Member", 
  "id": "1"
}, 
{
  "name": "Attender", 
  "id": "3"
}, 
{
  "name": "Child", 
  "id": "4"
}
```

How can I do that using Javascript?

Comment: isn't the `status` key has the same values in the array. Why don't you just do `response.statuses.status` where `response` is your variable name.

Comment: you just need to pull `response.statuses.status`?

Comment: Yes, you just need to retrieve by using response.statuses.status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var response = {
  "statuses": {
    "status": [
      {
        "name": "Member", 
        "id": "1"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "Attender", 
        "id": "3"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "Child", 
        "id": "4"
      }
    ]
  }
}

var statusObj = response.statuses.status;

$('#result').text('First name is: ' + statusObj[0].name)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id="result"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do [JSON.parse(str)](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp) and then you you just take the data from `status[x]`

If you really want to keep it as a string you can do 
`var content = str.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);`

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you just need to retrieve by response.statuses.status from your Javascript object.

But , If you needed to convert json to javascript object,
please use JSON.parse(your json response) method using JSON.js.

Download the JSON.js from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js